# Is there a realistic explanation, why depending on the time of the day the picture on a CRT monitor is shifter either right or left?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics, technology

Is there an explanation, why depending on the time of the day the picture on a CRT monitor is shifter either right or left, on a very old monitor (circa 1998)?

Comment: If you haven't already, you might confirm that it's a function of the time of day and not a function of how long the CRT has been turned on.  If you turn it on at the same time every day then maybe the picture is shifting during the day as the CRT temperature rises.

Answer (score 2):

CRTs work by controlling the flight of electrons with a magnetic field. A relatively constant magnetic field could cause a constant shift or offset in electrons' positions on the screen. Assuming the rest of the system is operating properly, likely there is an external source of magnetism (power lines or something) which has varying field strength throughout the day.